# Constraint satisfaction problem - Arc consistency

Tags: logic, algorithms, definition, intuition, model-theory

The [Constraint satisfaction problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_satisfaction_problem) (CSP) is roughly speaking a formalism that defines a finite set of relations over a domain. The relations are simply defined by enlisting elements in certain constraints.

A CSP can be *arc-consistent*. But I am struggeling to understand the definition given in my lecture:

A CSP $I=(X,D,C)$ ($X$ is the set of variables, $D$ the domain and $C$ the set of constraints that defines the relations) is arc-consistent if for all variables $x$ there is a constraint $(x,D_x)$ such that

- For all unary constraints $(x,P) \in C$ it holds that $D_x \subseteq P$
- For all binary constraints $((x,y),R) \in C$ it holds that
  $$D_x \subseteq \{a \mid \exists b \in D_y : (a,b) \in R\} $$
  and
  $$D_y \subseteq \{b \mid  \exists a \in D_x : (a,b) \in R \}$$

Thats fine so far but then there is an example for an instance of a CSP which is not arc consitent:
$$ \Bigg( \{x\}, ~~ \{1,2\}, ~~ \bigg\{\Big((x,x),\{(1,1)\}\Big), \Big(x,\{1,2\}\Big)\bigg\} \Bigg)$$

But in my opinion it is arc-consitent because $D_x=\{1\}$ satisfies all the conditions. Am I mistaken?

In addition to that the definition above is not equilvalent to the definition on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_consistency#Arc_consistency).

Any ideas?

Comment: You don't get to choose $D_x$, it is the domain of the variable. In your example, $D_x = \{1,2\}$ by the last constraint, which is not 2-consistent with the other relation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Antoine pointed out in his comment $D_x$ is not a set that can be chosen but the domain of the variable $x$. To obtain a arc-consistent instance one has to introduce so called domain constraints which restrict the domain of each variable independently.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the second constraint isn't needed because it says x should be in {1, 2}, but the first already requires that x is 1. Or am I reading this wrong?

Comment: Thats correct this is what makes it arc-inconsitent.